# How to convert TextView to int?

Tags: string, textview, int, ivalueconverter, parseint

I know that there are a lot of posts like this but I read them and my application does not work yet.
Im trying to convert TextView parameter into int. 
I use this:

```
int MyScore;
TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
MyScore = Integer.parseInt(score.toString());
```

When im launching the program and rich to the place this should work my program crushing becasue of the last line: `MyScore = Integer.parseInt(score.toString());`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line should read

```
    MyScore = Integer.parseInt(score.getText().toString());
```

The `toString()` method called on your `score` object describes the `score` object, it does not return the string entered into the `score` object. Please refer to the Oracle Java tutorials. It is a good idea to read through most of them.

Comment: using TextView.getText().toString() (like @Floris suggested) will return the text of the TextView. Works same for EditText if you will ever need.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify the language used I cannot answer fully, but I can guess what the problem is. Most input fields have a value or text property, try parsing that.